# How can I remove or insert an item from an instantiated listbox in another class?

Tags: python, tkinter

Good afternoon in this script I am trying to do the following tasks but they throw an error:

1- access the value that listbox has from the instantiator class.

2- delete the entire list of Listbox from a call of the Spinbox class to the Parent class: Frame_ class

I do not know if what I intend is well structured in the script or my logic is incorrect. A suggestion please. Thank you...

```
from tkinter import *

class Frame_class(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parents, *args, **kwargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, parents, *args, kwargs)
        self.listbox = Listbox_class (self, width=11, height=1)
        self.listbox .pack() 

        self.spinbox = Spinbox_class (self, width=11)
        self.spinbox .pack()
        
        # from here I want to get the value of 
        # the first item of listbox or delete it     

    def delete(self, number):
        if number == 1:
            self.listbox.delete(0, END)
        if number == 2:
            self.listbox.delete(0, 1)


class Listbox_class(Listbox, Frame_class):

    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
        Listbox.__init__(self, master, **kwargs)       
        self.config (font=('Calibri',9,'bold'))
        self.insert(0, 'banana1')
        self.insert(0, 'orange1')



class Spinbox_class(Spinbox, Frame_class):

    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
        Spinbox.__init__(self, master, **kwargs)
        self.var = StringVar() 
        self.val = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]      
        self.config (font=('Calibri',9,'bold'), textvariable= self.var, values= self.val)
        self.var.trace_add ('write', self.change)
        
      
    def change(self, *args):
        spinbox = self.get()

        if spinbox == '':                                                          
            Frame_class .delete(1)  
        else:  
            pass

root = Tk()
root.geometry('250x130+100+100')   
app =  Frame_class (root)
app . pack()
root.mainloop()
```

When trying to delete the content of spinbox, this code throws me the following error:
*TypeError: delete() missing 1 required positional argument: 'number'*

Comment: Your code contains syntax errors (spurious spaces) and wouldn't run as given. It's also unclear what line the error occurs on, please provide a script that allows someone to reproduce the problem and the full error message, including the information about where it occurred.

Comment: `Frame_class.delete(1)` is calling `delete(1)` on the class, not on the instance of the class.  Change it to `self.master.delete()` as `self.master` is the instance of `Frame_class`.

Comment: According to your posted code, it should be `self.master.listbox.get(0)`.  Also `if spinbox == ""` will always be evaluated as `False`, so `Frame_class.delete(1)` will never be executed and I wonder why you get the exception.  And I also wonder why you accepted the posted answer which cannot solve your issue.

Comment: How can we help if *"The code is incomplete"*? You better post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to instantiate a class instance here.
do this:

```
frame = Frame_class(root)
frame.delete(1)
```

full code:

```
from tkinter import *

class Frame_class(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parents, *args, **kwargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, parents, *args, kwargs)
        self.listbox = Listbox_class(self, width=11, height=1)
        self.listbox.pack() 

        self.spinbox = Spinbox_class(self, width=11)
        self.spinbox.pack()
        
        # from here I want to get the value of 
        # the first item of listbox or delete it     

    def delete(self, number):
        if number == 1:
            self.listbox.delete(0, END)
        if number == 2:
            self.listbox.delete(0, 1)


class Listbox_class(Listbox, Frame_class):

    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
        Listbox.__init__(self, master, **kwargs)       
        self.config(font=('Calibri',9,'bold'))
        self.insert(0, 'banana1')
        self.insert(0, 'orange1')



class Spinbox_class(Spinbox, Frame_class):

    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
        Spinbox.__init__(self, master, **kwargs)
        self.var = StringVar() 
        self.val = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]      
        self.config (font=('Calibri',9,'bold'), textvariable= self.var, values= self.val)
        self.var.trace_add ('write', self.change)
        
      
    def change(self, *args):
        spinbox = self.get()

        if spinbox == '':   
            frame = Frame_class(root)
            frame.delete(1)  
        else:  
            pass

root = Tk()
root.geometry('250x130+100+100')   
app =  Frame_class(root)
app.pack()
root.mainloop()
```